# Make that my categories displays each respective content isolatedly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a simple project that have five dynamic categories created from my /admin panel.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify    

class TimeStampModel(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, DetailView
from .models import Product, Category

class SingleCatView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'products/single_category.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SingleCatView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['products'] = Product.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:6]
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

class SingleProView(DetailView):

    template_name = 'products/single_product.html'
    model = Product
```

as you saw my models.py permitme create my own categories in my django admin panel (now I have 5 categories created). also i can create "products" and assign them to each category freely in admin panel too.

Actually i have my project adapted to show my products mixed together in a simple template.html, I can see all without filters.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .views import SingleCatView, SingleProView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^jbpfamilies/category/$', SingleCatView.as_view(), name='vista_category'),
    url(r'^jbpfamilies/category/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', SingleProView.as_view(), name='vista_product'),

)
```

**My question is how can I make a filter that allows me to isolate each product with its respective category? and thereby, each category's link show me their respective products.** like this:

```
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Category1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category5</a></li>
                </ul>
```

I would have to do a template to each category? or i can use my single_category.html for all categories like i done with my products, using a single template to show any product (I think that this is the better form)

If you see in my views.py, in categories class i have this:

```
context['products'] = Product.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:6]
```

I was thinking that is possible use a `Product.objects.filter` but i'm not sure how i can implement this and how build my concatenated url for a dynamic category

for now i have a simple_category.html showing all products of all categories:

```
<!-- Start Content -->
    <div id="content">
        <div class="container">

            <div class=" portfolio-page portfolio-4column">
            <ul id="portfolio-list" data-animated="fadeIn">
            {% for product in products %}
                <li>
                    <img src="{{ product.pimage0.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" />
                    <div class="portfolio-item-content">
                        <span class="header">{{ product.name }}</span>
                        <p class="body">{{ product.size }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="{% url 'products:vista_product' product.id %}"><i class="more">+</i></a>

                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Content -->
```

*Excuseme if my question is too much large, but i'm really confused in this point still reading the django documentation.*

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what your actual question is. Do you simply want a list of categories, with links to a set of category pages which each contain the products in that category?

Comment: yes sir, now i have five categories created in my admin panel and i only want to specify a list that allow me surf between categories,  since by now I can see everything in a simple template without the desired order. Thanks to evaluate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

**Here I am assuming product has a foreignkey relationship with category like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Now for **all categories**, view is like:

```
class AllCategories(ListView):
    model = Category
    template = 'category_all.html'
```

And the `category_all.html` template should look like this:

```
 <ul>
 {% for cat in object_list %}
      <li> <a href='{% url 'category_details' pk=cat.pk %}'></li> {{ cat.name }}</a> {# This url name has been defined in later section of this answer. #}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And for **single category**, view is like:

```
class SingleCat(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template = 'category_single.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       current_category = context['object']
       context['products'] = current_category.product_set.all()
       return context
```

url is like this:

```
...
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', SingleCat.as_view(), name='category_details'),
...
```

and template `category_single.html` is like:

```
<h3>{{ object.name }}</h3>    
<ul>
{% for prod in products %}  
    <li>{{ prod.name }} </li>    
{% enfor %}    
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks to ruddra and user640916, I resolved my questions with your helps, thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of pseudo code because I can't try it out myself right now, but this is one way of achieving what you want. Doing it like that, you don't even need a separate view for showing all or only one category's products.

View:

```
class ProductView(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        products = Products.objects.all() # show all by default
        # Check if the request had a GET query parameter with name 'cat'
        cat = self.request.GET.get('cat', None)
        if cat:
            # yes, then show only that given categories products
            products = products.filter(category=cat)
```

Template:

Loop over your category queryset to generate links pointing to your product view and add the GET parameter to each.

```
{% for c in categories %}
<li><a href="?cat={{c}}">{{c}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```